# Python iteration wont change

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, range

I want to "reset" my for loop so i thought i have to set my iterator i on 0, but it will continue with 1 etc. How do "reset" my for loop? I tried to set i on 0 but in the next step my for loop just continues with 1 and so on. g is just a list with 2 items and S is a String, ignore all that. Its just this iteration that wont work

```
for i in range(0, len(g)):
    print("gi = " + g[i])
    print(i)
    if g[i] in S:
        S = S.replace(g[i], "", 1)
        print(S)
        i = 0
        output += 1
```

Comment: what is your expected output, S, and g?

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you don't know how many iterations the loop will take in advance, use a while loop.

Comment: S is a simple string and g is a list wich contains 2 strings

Comment: You can't change the iteration variable.  It's going to step through the `range` regardless of what you do inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a while loop:

```
S='1112'
g=['1', '2']

i = 0
output =  0
while i < len(g):
    if g[i] in S:
        S = S.replace(g[i], "", 1)
        print(S)
        i = 0
        output += 1
    else:
        i += 1

print('Is S empty?', S=='')
```

output:

```
112
12
2

Is S empty? True
```

Comment: @LeKerkiii so if you have `S='123'` and `g=['1', '2']` thisi will print : `23` and `3` ? (ignore the fact that S has 3 elements

Comment: @LeKerkiii if you have `S='1112'` and `g=['1', '2']` this will print :`112` then `12`, then `2` then nothing ? at the ent `S` will be an empty string?

Comment: yes kind of i tried everything but i wont work i dont know

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `for` loop; use a `while`:

```
i = 0
while i < len(g):
    <your original loop body; might need to replace i=0 with i=-1>
    i += 1
```

Comment: Does not fix my problem i will stay at 0 and does not count up